# Can we create two sockets with same portnumber

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create a client-server model using socket programming in Java. I have multiple clients connecting to a server socket, but once the connection is lost, I need to reconnect to the server but using the same port number for the client. I have data stored on the server with respect to the port number through which it came. Is it possible to get the same port number for a socket again?

Comment: No. And it makes no sense to do so. Only one socket can own a port at a time.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, it is possible

Comment: That is correct. It is possible, but you will have to wait for the TIME_WAIT state to expire before you can do it, and you don't have a simple way to do with. It is at least two minutes. You need to find another mechanism if you want to resume the same session.

Comment: Essentially, you need to **implement** the concept of a session connection that can exist across multiple (sequential) transport connections.

Comment: @user207421 you can use `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT` to get around the `TIME_WAIT` issue. Also, the client socket will enter `TIME_WAIT` only if the client intentionally disconnects gracefully. But if the connection is lost abnormally, there won't be any `TIME_WAIT` state entered.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, if you used SO_REUSEADDR every time, but your own answer says 'Just note that it may take some time for the OS to release the port from the previous connection before it can be reused again. '

Comment: @user207421 that is if the `REUSE` options are NOT used. If they ARE used, a local port can be reused more quickly for a new connection (if you understand and accept the risks of doing so).

Answer (score 3):

The server has no control over which port a client connects from.

On the client side, however, a socket can be `bind()`'ed to a specific local IP/Port before it is then `connect()`'ed to the server. Just note that it may take some time for the OS to release the port from the previous connection before it can be reused again. And also, if the client has to connect through a proxy/router to reach the server, the IP the server sees will be the proxy/router's IP, not the client's IP, and there is no guarantee that the port which the server sees will be the same port which the client is using.

The real question is, why are you relying on something unreliable like a client ip/port to store your data? I would suggest using a unique ID to identify the data, like say a user login, or a server-generated ID that is given to the client. If the client disconnects and reconnect, it can just login/send back the same ID.